# node.js, ожидание обновления mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Добрый день! Задача на первый взгляд очень простая, но закопался.
Есть *php* приложение, добавляет данные в *mysql*. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при добавлении строки в таблицу, всплывало *realtime* сообщение на странице. Видится, что нужен *node.js* и *socket.io*. Подскажите что-нибудь, спасибо!

Comment: по хорошему php должно при добавлении записи дернут какой нибудь сервис на сервере (не будет же он в цикле каждую секунду базу перечитывать). А вот сервис должен после этого сообщить ожидающим клиентам ... Копать в сторону WebSocket. Потому как без WebSocket клиенский браузер должен ежесекундно слать ajax запросы "А не появилось ли новостей"

Comment: Даже если и слать ajax - то как должен выглядеть запрос "не появилось ли новых данных"?

Comment: Да собственно как угодно. Обычный запрос, как параметры видимо ID последнего события которое есть у клиента или серверное время последнего известного события.Главное что бы сервер понял с какой точки события давать

Comment: Все равно не догоняю ) В таблице к примеру 3 колонки, ID (AI), NAME, DATE. Проставляется ID, пишется имя, и заносится время создания записи.

Comment: Ну если конкретный ID уже есть у клиента, и ID всегда растет то видимо клиенту надо отдать все записи у которых ID больше того что он сообщил

Comment: Предложили такую логику: Пишем одновременно с основной записью, запись в другую таблицу. Ее опрашиваем в цикле, по условию кол-во рядов больше нуля, и с каждым проходом цикла делаем то что нужно, и удаляем запись. Мне кажется нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте библиотеку elephant.io
https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io
Использую в нескольких проектах, для связки socket.io + php.

Достаточно после добавления данных в таблицу, спомощью библиотеки, отправить emit на socket.io. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю!